# How to create a "distinct" queue in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-worker-roles

I've got the following theoretical problem.

I'd like to be able to create multiple instances of every role in my Azure application. At least 2, to make sure it's working 24/7 (or nearly 24/7).

This is easy for client front-ends and roles which listen for data.

It's also easy for worker roles which process data and save results in blobs / table-storage assuming each worker role processes it's own set of data to create a single result.

But I'm having a problem with the "middle" of this application.

In the simplest case, if I could create an Azure storage "distinct" queue (no two messages are identical), then it would be easy. But as far as I know, this cannot be done, especially since you can download only 32 messages at a time.

So, I'd need some sort of controller role... I think. This role would ensure the worker roles wouldn't interfere with each other.

BUT, this means the controller role cannot have more than one instance!

How should I approach this problem?

EDIT:

I see I may have given too little information regarding my problem.

I am aware how Azure queues work; I know that once a message is dequeued it won't be available for other roles for a period of time or until it is deleted.

The thing is, I cannot just populate the queue with random, unique data, like GUIDs.

Here's a more down-to-earth explanation of the problem.

- Listener roles listen for client data, and place that data into a base table, then notify, via a queue, that a specific part of that table has been altered.
- Listener roles may report that the same part of the table has been modified multiple times - they don't track what's going on with the queue, and what's already in it, so they just send out messages along the lines of "hey, I modified this bit for this client" (for example).
- Workers create or refresh specific files (blobs mostly) based on the messages provided by the listeners. Currently, there's a single worker, which downloads the entire queue, checks for distinct messages, and then refreshes all the files as needed. Adding a second worker causes problems: since the queue usually DOESN'T contain distinct values, two workers could start working on the same output file, and interrupt each other.

Thus, I'm looking for a queue that is distinct, or at least provides a way to check if a specific message hasn't already been placed in it.

If the Service Bus is the only way to go, then so be it, but it would be nice to make the solution as simple as possible. ;)

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're asking. Can you elaborate a bit? Why can't you add distinct messages to a queue? How is a 32-message read limit related to distinct messages? How would worker roles interfere with each other without a controller role?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Service Bus queues do have the concept of unique messages (which may be what you mean by distinct). There is nice comparison between the two types of queue here:

http://preps2.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/comparison-of-windows-azure-storage-queues-and-service-bus-queues/

The problem of having a single process in a resilient infrastructure can be solved using locking. You can use blob storage as a lock, as demonstrated by smarx's blob post:

http://blog.smarx.com/posts/managing-concurrency-in-windows-azure-with-leases

However, I would consider your whole architecture, and try to reduce the number roles you're using. I set out some arguments for this in a recent blog post:

http://coderead.wordpress.com/2012/03/23/three-tier-architecture-in-the-cloud/

Comment: We, currently, have very few roles in out solution. What we WOULD like to be able to do is scale the project as needed, depending on the workload, which in it's current implementation isn't possible.

Answer (score 2):

`But as far as I know, this cannot be done, especially since you can download only 32 messages at a time.`

It is not the case. When you read items from the Queue, the items doesn't appear in queue for a given amount of time(Configurable). Once the processing is done, you can dequeue the message. Generation of Queue ID can be unique & the simplest & straight forward way to use a GUID. You can use this to develop a system which reads unique key items.

The ultimate reason why someone uses a queue is to exactly the solve the complexity of multiple worker roles taking input from Queue without any problem.

Comment: I am aware that a message downloaded from the queue will NOT be downloaded by another worker role until a certain amount of time expires (or the message is just deleted). But this isn't the case. The problem is I cannot just populate the queue with random GUIDs to make them unique. The point is that there's a certain amount of data which may or may not need to be refreshed, and I'd like to refresh it in the most optimal way possible. Normally I'd get the elements that need to be worked on, and place them in the queue, provided such an element isn't already there.

Answer (score 1):

If the front end roles are logging the requests into an Azure Storage queue, then that queue can be leveraged by the workers to do distributed processing of the requests. WHen one worker instance reads a message from the queue, that message is no longer visible to any other worker instances for a given amount of time (which you can increase by periodically reknewing the lease on the message). This prevents two workers from both processing the same messages.

Alternatively, you can use a pattern for self electing a controller instance. This pattern says that the process for the controller exists in all role instances. When the instances start up, the process first tries to obtain an exclusive lock on an object, like leasing an Azure Storage blob object. The first one to obtain the lease becomes the "controller", the rest go to sleep to wait and periodically check to see if the blob is available for lease again. This allows another instance to take over being the controller if the first becomes unavailable (it becomes self healing in a manner of speaking).

I thik the first approach would be my first choice as it doesn't require alot of complex coding. But depending on what you're trying to accomplish, the second one can also be a decent solution if you're willing to invest the time.